# JavaScript pass array of strings issue

Tags: javascript, playframework

From my play! framework view I pass an array of strings to my js method like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        buildMapWithMarkers('map_canvas', ${hotelsLat}, ${hotelsLng}, ${hotelsNames}), 'false'); 
    </script>
```

The problem is that sometimes `hotelsNames` contains strings having `'` or `&` eg `Hyatt's Green`:

```
buildMapWithMarkers('map_canvas', [43.3484420, 43.614980, 43.549480], [-97.4318550, -97.61660500000001, -97.5021910], [Sportsmans Acres Pheasant Hunts, Hyatt's Green Acres, Guest Room Motel]), 'false');
```

so it throws some exceptions:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Can you please help me how to encode this (in view or controller)?

I tried: `encodeURIComponent(${hotelsNames})` but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your strings need to be surrounded in quotes and backslash escaped.

So that " and ' print out as \" and \'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by:

- escaping chars JS does not "like"
- surrounding with quotes

  `final String hotelName = StringEscapeUtils                     .escapeJavaScript(hotel.name);
  hotelsNames.add("'" + hotelName + "'");`